# RxSwift - How to create two streams from one upstream

Tags: rx-swift

#### Background

I'm trying to observe one `Int` stream (actually I'm not, but to make the argument easier) and do something with it while combining that stream to multiple other streams, say a `String` stream and a `Double` stream like the following:

```swift
// RxSwift
let intStream = BehaviorSubject<Int>(value: 0) // subscribe to this later on
let sharedStream = intStream.share()
let mappedStream = sharedStream.map { ... }.share()
let combinedStream1 = Observable.combineLatest(sharedStream, stringStream).map { ... }
let combinedStream2 = Observable.combineLatest(sharedStream, doubleStream).map { ... }
```

The above code is just to demonstrate what I'm trying to do. The code above is part of view model code (the VM part of MVVM), and only the first `map` (for `mappedStream`) runs, while the others are not called.

#### Question

What is wrong with the above approach, and how do I achieve what I'm trying to do?
Also, is there a better way to achieve the same effect?

#### Updates

- I confirmed that setting the replay count to `1` makes things work. But why?
- The code above all goes in the initialization phase of the view model, and the subscription happens afterwards.

Comment: Can you say a little more about why you are trying to do this? Observing your intStream can be done simply by subscribing to it so I assume what you need is more complex. The only reason why your code doesn't compile is because of the `...`s in it. What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: @DanielT. Thanks for the comment. I was being vague a little intentionally because I wasn't sure if `share` is even the right way to go about it. Subscription doesn't work in this case because I'm reacting to a change in the view model; other changes need to be made simultaneously.

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What doesn't work about it? When it is "working" what does that mean?

Comment: My bad. The code doesn't run.

Comment: I still don't understand. There's a lot of lazy code here so it not running doesn't mean much either...

Comment: The fact that subscription happens later wasn't enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have an answer but it's a bit complex... One problem is that you are using a Subject in the view model, but I'll ignore that for now. The real problem comes from the fact that you are using hot observables inappropriately (`share()` make a stream hot) and so events are getting dropped.

It might help if you put a bunch of `.debug()`s on this code so you can follow along. But here's the essence...

When you subscribe to `mappedStream`, it subscribes to the `share` which in turn subscribes to the sharedStream, which subscribes to the intStream. The intStream then emits the 0, and that 0 goes down the chain and shows up in the observer.

Then you subscribe to the `combinedStream1`, which subscribes to the sharedStream's share(). Since this share has already been subscribed to, the subscriptions stop there, and since the share has already output it's next event, the `combinedStream1` doesn't get the .next(0) event.

Same for the `combinedStream2`.

Get rid of all the `share()`s and everything will work:

```
let intStream = BehaviorSubject<Int>(value: 0) // subscribe to this later on
let mappedStream = intStream.map { $0 }
let combinedStream1 = Observable.combineLatest(intStream, stringStream).map { $0 }
let combinedStream2 = Observable.combineLatest(intStream, doubleStream).map { $0 }
```

This way, each subscriber of `intStream` gets the `0` value.

The only time you want to share is if you need to share side effects. There aren’t any side effects in this code, so there’s no need to share.

Comment: As you have already noticed, putting a replay: 1 on the share also works because it forces the share to replay it's latest value to each subscriber.

Comment: Ah.. Makes sense. And like you mentioned, it works like it's supposed to when removing the `share`.

One more question if you're willing to answer: Why do you think using a `Subject` in a model is a problem? The subject is used to run commands from the user; i.e. something like `viewModel.update(1)` runs `subject.onNext(input)` inside the view model. (As you might have noticed, I'm not too familiar with Rx)

Comment: Subjects are for converting non-Rx code into Rx, and to handle cycles in a stream. Neither is the case here. Handle user input with RxCocoa.

Comment: Hmm... I think we're talking about slightly different things. The view model needs a default state, a selection index, which I used a `Subject` for. When a user selects from a list in the UI, a method in the view model is called. Inside the method, the selected index is updated, which should be propagated to the combined streams, where update happens reactively. Not sure where RxCocoa comes into play here.

Comment: No we aren't. You are still stuck in an imperative mindset. Your view model should be a single function not a class with a bunch of methods. Check out some examples in the #rxmvvm channel in the [RxSwift slack](http://slack.rxswift.org)